# cant change a login scrreen or always shows this screen on startup

Tags: login-screen, lock-screen, lock

When ever I open it shows this old type.

this is scrreen looks like on startup
[image]

Comment: That looks legit, what's the probelm ? What versionand flavour of Ubuntu ?

Comment: You have installed some packages which auto configured your login manager away from gdm3..

Comment: What's happening when you run this command in terminal.. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`